# Escribir length en StreamWriter

Tags: c#

Buenos días. Estoy intentando mediante WebRequest enviar un json mediante el método PUT. 
Al llegar a httpWebRequest.GetResponse() me da error.

> Debe escribir ContentLength bytes en el flujo de la solicitud antes de llamar a [Begin]GetResponse.

Al escribir en el StreamWriter la propiedad length como en la de posotion me da una excepción.

> '(writer.BaseStream).length' produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   '(writer.BaseStream).position' produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.NotSupportedException'

Como podría rellenar el length y el position.

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = metodo.ContentType;

httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonData = jsSerializer.Serialize(datosPUT);
byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);

httpWebRequest.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
httpWebRequest.Expect = "application/json";

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(arrData);
writer.Close()
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); //AQUÍ EL ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el error que te da tiene pinta que no esta terminando de hacer flush en el stream antes de llamar al GetResponse, prueba a escribir el código de esta manera:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = metodo.ContentType;

httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonData = jsSerializer.Serialize(datosPUT);
byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);

httpWebRequest.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
httpWebRequest.Expect = "application/json";
using (var dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
   dataStream.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Usando using te aseguras que el stream se cierra correctamente.

[Pregunta similar en la versión inglesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297612/system-net-protocolviolationexception-you-must-write-contentlength-bytes-to-the)

Comment: Sigue dando la misma excepción

Comment: ¿Con la ultima versión del código que he puesto te sigue dando error? Lo he probado y reponde correctamente, ten en cuenta que llamo directamente al write en el stream en vez de crear un StreamWriter

Comment: Sigue sin rellenar las propiedades de length y position pero al llegar al GetResponse, ya sale otro error un 401 no autorizado, pero eso ya es otra historia xD